# How to print selected emails from GMail conversation only using Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is there no way to print selected emails from a non-conversational email series of replies and sends using Gmail alone?  I am using a system to which I cannot add programs.

Answer (score 1):

To print just specific parts of a conversation you will need to print each reply/send individually from the conversation.

Make sure the individual email is expanded and then click the dropdown arrow.

[image]

Then click print.

[image]

To print an entire email chain:

[image]

To the right of the subject line is a tiny print button.

[image]

If you click the printer button it will automatically bring up the print popup for whatever browser you're using.